# How to receive resource finish loading callback from android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a use case which needs to hook up a Javascript call after an js resource has been loaded in the Android WebView. I found there is already a callback `onLoadResource` from `WebViewClient` but this is called **before** loading a resource, but not after. May I know how to achieve this?

(P.S. As a workaround now, I just keep on running the Javascript statements during the callback `onProgressChanged` and the Javascript statements may return error since the corresponding js objects may not be ready yet.)

Comment: hi David, any work around for that